# permissionsdispatcher and multiple @NeedsPermission's with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

For one permission I can use permissionsdispatcher in java and kotlin - but when it comes to multiple permissions like this:

```
@NeedsPermission({Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH})
```

I get a problem on kotlin - it does not accept more than one parameter there - works fine with java

Comment: Could you please elaborate -- what Kotlin code exactly have you tried and what was the error?

Comment: Is you question about the syntax for this case? `@NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)` seems to be working. Java's `String[] value();` is recognized as a vararg parameter in Kotlin.

Comment: @AndroidEx with which version of kotlin is this working for you? I run 1.0.3 and this syntax fails here

Comment: @ligi 1.0.3. Strangely, the accepted answer doesn't work for me with `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.Array<kotlin.String> but kotlin.String was expected`, I have to add `*` before `arrayOf` to spread it into vararg.

Comment: You are right - I editet the answer

Comment: try removing your `{}` curly braces, you do not need an array if the type `@NeedsPermission` is vararg.  If it is an array, then `arrayOf(something, somethingelse)`, if vararg just `something, somethingelse`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java the `{}` represents creating an array, and in this context in Kotlin the `{}` is accidentally creating a [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) and it cannot be determined what you intend because the code inside the lambda is invalid.

So you are saying `@NeedsPermission(someFunctionReferenceThatIsInvalid)` instead of passing in an array of permissions as `@NeedsPermission(array)`

In the annotation the array is being treated as a `vararg` so you can just list the elements:

```
@NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
```

If it were being treated as an array, you would use the `arrayOf` function:

```
@NeedsPermission(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH))
```

The examples creating an array and then using the [`*` spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-varargs) are basically doing and then undoing the array and it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
@NeedsPermission(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH))
```

In java `@NeedsPermission({...})` the curly brackets `{...}` is just a shorthand for creating an array. In kotlin you must explicitly say that it is an array, because `{}` is reserved for lambda expressions.

Comment: the `*` is undoing your `array` so remove both, if it is vararg just list the elements without any special creation of array or using the spread operator.

Comment: That has been modified by someone else, my original answer didn't have the `*`